# Iterate list of colors regardless of length of index of dataframes - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, list, loops, colors, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebook. I have DataFrames that when created are never the same length and would like to apply a list of colors I define on a unique value of a column. The DataFrames do share the same column I intend to color based on unique values. Where I am getting stuck is if the length of the DataFrame index is greater than the number of colors listed in my list I receive an error saying "IndexError: list index out of range". I would like to continue to iterate with my list of colors regardless the length of unique values in the below example, column x1.

Below I have a one off MRE that should be able to test. You will note that df3 works correctly due to column x1 having the same length of values as colors in my list whereas df4 throws an error due to column x1 having more values than colors in my list.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd'],
                     'x2':['3', '4', '8', '0', '11', '1']})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':['a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'h'],
                     'x2':['0', '41', '22', '5', '19', '21', '5', '7', '8', '24', '15']})
```

```
def Color_Unique(s):
    df = s.copy()
    color_map = {}

    Trade_Cusip_Combo_Key = df['x1'].unique()
    colors_to_use = ['background-color: #ADD8E6', 'background-color: #90ee90', 'background-color: #FFD580', 'background-color: #CBC3E3', 'background-color: #D3D3D3', 'background-color: #C4A484']

    for Trade_Cusip_Combo in Trade_Cusip_Combo_Key:
        color_map[Trade_Cusip_Combo] = colors_to_use[0]
        colors_to_use.pop(0)

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['x1'] in Trade_Cusip_Combo_Key:
            Trade_Cusip_Combo = row['x1']
            my_color = color_map[Trade_Cusip_Combo]
            df.loc[index,:] = my_color
        else:
            df.loc[index,:] = 'background-color: '        
    return df
```

```
df3 = df1.style.apply(Color_Unique, axis=None)
```

```
df3
```

```
df4 = df2.style.apply(Color_Unique, axis=None)
```

```
df4
```

Comment: I am on Linux, no Jupyter. Your code runs without any problems.

Comment: @Claudio df4 returns a highlighted dataframe based on unique values of column x1? For me my error is "IndexError: list index out of range'...

Comment: @Claudio here is the exact message:                                                               
      `<ipython-input-84-cf595ad7bc81> in Color_Unique(s)
      7 
      8     for Trade_Cusip_Combo in Trade_Cusip_Combo_Key:
----> 9         color_map[Trade_Cusip_Combo] = colors_to_use[0]
     10         colors_to_use.pop(0)
     11 

IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: OK ... with help of @Thierry Lathuille I found a way to reproduce the error  on my system and ... his answer should give you what you were after right? Or have you any further questions? Sorry ... I was not aware of lazy evaluation of  pandas .apply() and learned a lesson from it. I will delete my comment, so you can delete yours as well. See you next question :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily loop through your list of colors, going back to the start once you reach the end, by using [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) that will cycle through the list indefinitely.

We first create the cycle object with:

```
from itertools import cycle


colors_to_use = ['background-color: #ADD8E6', 'background-color: #90ee90', 
                 'background-color: #FFD580', 'background-color: #CBC3E3',
                 'background-color: #D3D3D3', 'background-color: #C4A484']
colors_cycle = cycle(colors_to_use)
```

Then you can get the next color with the `next` function:

```
print(next(colors_cycle))
print(next(colors_cycle))
```

outputs:

```
background-color: #ADD8E6
background-color: #90ee90
```

So, the coloring part of your code becomes: (don't forget `from itertools import cycle` at the beginning of your script)

```
colors_to_use = ['background-color: #ADD8E6', 'background-color: #90ee90', 'background-color: #FFD580', 'background-color: #CBC3E3', 'background-color: #D3D3D3', 'background-color: #C4A484']
colors_cycle = cycle(colors_to_use)

for Trade_Cusip_Combo in Trade_Cusip_Combo_Key:
    color_map[Trade_Cusip_Combo] = next(colors_cycle)
```

and you get this output, where colors start looping again from blue after brown:

[image: df4 with cycling colors]

The complete code (with imports) of the Jupyter cell:

```
from itertools import cycle
import pandas as pd


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':['a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'h'],
                     'x2':['0', '41', '22', '5', '19', '21', '5', '7', '8', '24', '15']})

def Color_Unique(s):
    df = s.copy()
    color_map = {}

    Trade_Cusip_Combo_Key = df['x1'].unique()
    colors_to_use = ['background-color: #ADD8E6', 'background-color: #90ee90', 'background-color: #FFD580', 'background-color: #CBC3E3', 'background-color: #D3D3D3', 'background-color: #C4A484']
    colors_cycle = cycle(colors_to_use)

    for Trade_Cusip_Combo in Trade_Cusip_Combo_Key:
        color_map[Trade_Cusip_Combo] = next(colors_cycle)

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['x1'] in Trade_Cusip_Combo_Key:
            Trade_Cusip_Combo = row['x1']
            my_color = color_map[Trade_Cusip_Combo]
            df.loc[index,:] = my_color
        else:
            df.loc[index,:] = 'background-color: '        
    return df

df4 = df2.style.apply(Color_Unique, axis=None)
df4
```

Comment: @Claudio, thank you so much for your work done here. I am attempting to install cycle and receive an error: 

` SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("cycle only supports Python 2.7 and higher")?
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ai81jael/cycle/`

do you know how to resolve this so I can implement the code you shared above?

Comment: Is it because I am using Python3 and this package only supports Python2?

Comment: There is nothing to install, the itertools module that contains the cycle function is part of the standard library. Just add the import, exactly as it is in my answer, at the start of your code. And btw, I'm Thierry, not Claudio.

Comment: I am unable to replicate the success you had into my code, could you please elaborate if you kept the function or how this worked for you? I would really appreciate it!!

Comment: Added the complete, working code of the cell, with all imports. Just copy, paste and run it.

Comment: sorry to be a pain but I have an additional question. Should I raise a new question?

Comment: Thank you Thierry! My project needs changed and had to alter the function your cleverly helped me create. Here is my new problem if you want to have a stab at it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73887953/iterate-list-of-colors-based-on-unique-column-value-using-a-value-from-a-second