# Iterate list of colors based on unique column value using a value from a second column to differ between dark and light colors - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, colors, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebook. I have combined two DataFrames together, so in order to differentiate between the two I have created a new third column 'Color Code' where there are two values 'a' and 'b'. I have no problem iterating through the list of colors I have defined but I need to be able to color dark vs light depending on the unique columns and 'Color Code' column.

I have an MRE below. Apologies for the big example DataFrame, just need to be able to showcase what I am trying to accomplish.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd'],
                     'x2':['3','4','8','0','11','1','15','5','67','3','1','4','5','88','9','3','7','2','3','43','34','56','96','26'],
                     'Color Mode':['a','a','b','b','b','b','a','a','a','a','b','b','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','a','a','a','b']})
```

```
def Color_Unique(s):
    df = s.copy()
    
    color_map1 = {}
    color_map2 = {}

    x = pd.DataFrame({'Color Mode': ['a']})
    y = pd.DataFrame({'Color Mode': ['b']})
    
    Trade_Cusip_Combo_Key = df['x1'].unique()
    
    if x.any(axis=None):
        colors_to_use = ['background-color: #ADD8E6', 'background-color: #90ee90', 'background-color: #FFD580', 'background-color: #CBC3E3', 'background-color: #D3D3D3', 'background-color: #C4A484']
        colors_cycle = cycle(colors_to_use)

        for Trade_Cusip_Combo in Trade_Cusip_Combo_Key:
            color_map1[Trade_Cusip_Combo] = next(colors_cycle)

        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if row['x1'] in Trade_Cusip_Combo_Key:
                Trade_Cusip_Combo = row['x1']
                my_color = color_map1[Trade_Cusip_Combo]
                df.loc[index,:] = my_color
            else:
                df.loc[index,:] = 'background-color: '        
        return df
    elif y.any(axis=None):
        colors_to_use = ['background-color: #ADD8E6', 'background-color: #90ee90', 'background-color: #FFD580', 'background-color: #CBC3E3', 'background-color: #D3D3D3', 'background-color: #C4A484']
        colors_cycle = cycle(colors_to_use)

        for Trade_Cusip_Combo in Trade_Cusip_Combo_Key:
            color_map2[Trade_Cusip_Combo] = next(colors_cycle)

        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if row['x1'] in Trade_Cusip_Combo_Key:
                Trade_Cusip_Combo = row['x1']
                my_color = color_map2[Trade_Cusip_Combo]
                df.loc[index,:] = my_color
            else:
                df.loc[index,:] = 'background-color: '        
        return df
    else:
        print("boken")
```

```
df4 = df1.style.apply(Color_Unique, axis=None)
```

```
df4
```

[This is what my code currently looks like when you run my above MRE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAvpo.png)

[This is what I need it to look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv3cd.png)

You will notice dark vs light colors alternate when column 'x1' values are the same but column 'Color Mode' values are either 'a' (dark color) or 'b' (lighter color). I need my function to be able to iterate through my defined dark and light colors based on column 'x1' and column ' Color Mode' as well as skip a line after each group is colored (blue to green to orange to purple).

```
new_df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':['axe', 'axe', 'axe', 'axe', 'axe', 'axe', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 
                          'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'crunch', 'crunch', 'crunch', 'crunch', 'crunch', 'crunch', 
                          'crunch', 'crunch', 'deed', 'deed', 'deed', 'deed'],
                     'x2':['Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Leo','Leo','Leo','Leo',
                           'Leo','Leo','Jamie','Jamie','Jamie','Jamie','Jamie','Jamie','Jamie','Jamie',
                           'John','John','John','Luke'],
                     'Price':['3.00','3.00','3.00','3.00','3.00','3.00','15.00','80.00','15.00','15.00',
                           '15.00','15.00','4.00','4.00','4.00','68.00','4.00','4.00','39.00','4.00',
                           '5.00','5.00','5.00','27.00'],
                    'Color Mode':['a','a','b','b','b','b','a','a','a',
                           'a','b','b','a','b','b','b','b','b',
                           'b','b','a','a','a','b']})
```

new picture:
[New Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9bhZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before turning to the "styling" part of the exercise, let's use a function to insert blank rows into your df. We can do this as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 
                          'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 
                          'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd'],
                     'x2':['3','4','8','0','11','1','15','5','67','3',
                           '1','4','5','88','9','3','7','2','3','43',
                           '34','56','96','26'],
                     'Color Mode':['a','a','b','b','b','b','a','a','a',
                                   'a','b','b','a','b','b','b','b','b',
                                   'b','b','a','a','a','b']})

def blank_rows(df, col_name):
    insert_idx = [v[-1]+1 for v in df.groupby(col_name).groups.values()]
    for i, idx in enumerate(insert_idx[:-1]):
        temp = pd.DataFrame({k: '' for k in df.columns}, index=[idx+i])
        df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:idx+i], temp, df.iloc[idx+i:]])\
        .reset_index(drop=True)
    return df

# add `col_name` (e.g. `x1`) to specify which groups need to be split up
df = blank_rows(df1, 'x1')

# N.B. the groups inside column `col_name` need to be sorted, 
# and the index needs to be "regular" (i.e. `0,1,2...`).
# E.g. `df = blank_rows(df1, 'Color Mode')` would get you a nonsensical result;
# Instead you would want to use: 
# `df = blank_rows(df1.sort_values('Color Mode').reset_index(drop=True), 
#                'Color Mode')`
```

`df` will now contain empty rows like below:

```
df.iloc[[5,6,7,12,13,14],:]
```

[image]

Now, let's apply a function to take care of the styles. E.g.:

```
from itertools import cycle

def color_unique(df_input):
    df = df_input.copy()
    colors = ['#8EA9DB', '#D9E1F2', # blues
              '#A9D08E', '#E2EFDA', # greens
              '#F4B084', '#FCE4D6', # reds
              '#9751CB', '#DEC8EE'] # purples

    colors_cycle = cycle(colors)
        
    groups = df.groupby(['x1','Color Mode']).groups
    for k, v in groups.items():
        if '' in k:  
            df.iloc[v] = f'background-color: white;'
        else:
            df.iloc[v] = f'background-color: {next(colors_cycle)};'
    return df

df_styled = df.style.apply(color_unique, axis=None)
df_styled
```

Result:

[image]

**Explanation**

- Create a list with dark/light color pairs. Since we are using `cycle` from `itertools`, the list does not need to be exhaustive. (**N.B.**: the above function *is* expecting that each group in `x1` is *always* split in 2 subgroups based on `Color Mode`. E.g. if you expect groups that only have `a`, not `b`, the above function would need to be adjusted!)
- Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to isolate the different groups. Make sure to add `sort=False` to preserve the *original* order of the groups.
- The [`Groupby.groups`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html) property stores a `dict` with "group name" (e.g. `('a', 'a')`) as keys and the associated index values as values (e.g. for `('a', 'a')` the value is `Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')`.
- We want to use the values per group to select slices consecutively from the df with [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and assign a color. However, we want to skip the group that has key `(''),('')`, For that reason, we want to iterate over [`group.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) and catch both the `(k)ey` and `(v)alue`. If the key (tuple) contains an empty string, we color the row "white", else we assign the next color from our list of colors.

Comment: will there be an issue if the dataframe I pass through the blank rows function differs in the length of the index? I am noticing if I pass through a larger dataframe the blank rows are not correctly separating each unique x1 value.

Comment: yes, this is what I am noticing. so I ran with the following: `df = blank_rows(df1.sort_values('x1').reset_index(drop=False),  'x1')`. If I keep drop = False you will see the index has changed from the original for x1 = crunch and x1 = deed. I need those to stay in the exact order as df1.

Comment: The index is now: `Int64Index([7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,{BLANK ROW}, 21, 20, 19, 18, 16, 15, 14, 17,{BLANK ROW}, 25, 23, 24, 26...]`

Comment: yes, it  is a problem. I need the index to be in the same order as df1 similar to how x1 = bench is correct with `Int64Index([7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12...])`

Comment: Apologies I am using the new_df1 above in my question I just edited.

Comment: I need 8 & 9 to be consecutive is the issue I am running into.

Comment: So, if I feed your `new_df1` to the function *without sorting anything* (it is already sorted), I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7g3A.png. What's wrong with that result? It's exactly what I would expect it to be.

Comment: correct, the first time i use the function `def blank_rows(df, col_name):...` it works perfectly. It is when I go to apply it again is where I get this issue. Poting a picture to my answer for more info.

Comment: Just added the picture, do you see how x1 = crunch index #13 was previously index #14 and #21, #20 are all ahead of it? I need crunch to be sequential with 14, 15,16, 17, 18, 19, 29, 21. Same with x1 =deed need that to be 23, 24, 25, 26.

Comment: Right, but you're not showing what you are using as input the 2nd time you use the function. E.g. if I do `df = blank_rows(df.loc[df.x1 != ''][6:].reset_index(drop=False), 'x1') / df_styled = df.style.apply(color_unique, axis=None)`, then the result is again just what I would expect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF4He.png. This looks *sort of* like the `df` you are apparently inputting, but clearly not *exactly*, else you would obviously have gotten the same proper result. Anyway, I'm pretty sure that the reordering of column *index* is happening *before* you pass it to `blank_rows`.